# XML / XSD how to create a key

Tags: xml, xsd, key

I am having problems defining a key in XML Schema.

**CODE:**

XSD:

```
 <xsd:element name="players">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="player" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="date-of-birth" type="xsd:date"></xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="gender">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="MALE" />
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="FEMALE" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:all>
                    <xsd:attribute name="username" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                </xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:key name="playerkey">
                    <xsd:selector xpath="players/player" />
                    <xsd:field xpath="username" />
                </xsd:key>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Note that this is only an exzerpt from the full code, but it shows all necessary information.

XML

```
<t:players>
    <t:player username="Super Mario">
        <t:gender>FEMALE</t:gender>
        <t:date-of-birth>1995-11-29</t:date-of-birth>
    </t:player>
    <t:player username="Super Mario">
        <t:date-of-birth>1991-10-12</t:date-of-birth>
        <t:gender>MALE</t:gender>
    </t:player>
</t:players>
```

**PROBLEM:**

As you can see I have created two players with both the name "Super Mario". Since the key should be unique this should throw and error, but xmllins does validate the files correctly

**QUESTION:**

How do I define the key correctly, that the elements are necessary to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move the key declaration to the level where it applies, in this case I assume you want the each <player> to be unique among all <players>
2. The Xpath expression is wrong in your schema; username is an attribute and must have an `@` prefix.
3. If elements selected by the key has a non empty namespace, the xapth expression must also be qualified with
   those nanespaces.

> ```
>  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>     elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="xyzzy" xmlns:t="xyzzy">
>     <xsd:element name="players">
>        <xsd:complexType>
>             ...
>     </xsd:complexType>
>     <xsd:key name="playerkey">
>         <xsd:selector xpath="t:player" />
>         <xsd:field xpath="@username" />
>     </xsd:key>
>     </xsd:element>
> </xsd:schema>
> ```

Updated  with namespace qualification.

Comment: Thanx for you help, but sadly it still won`t work.
I moved they key into players and changed the xpath but it still validates correctly with two nonunique elements

Comment: Ok the namespace was the problem :D
It works now, thanks for your help mate! :)

Answer (score 1):

In XSD, if you want every element E within some element R to have a unique value for F, then the declaration of R needs to include a key definition in which the selector selects E from R, and the field selects F from E.